# como configuro mongoose para que me guarde en zona horaria -5:00?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, express, mongoose

Buenas noches compañeros, me encuentro estancado en la zona horaria dde mongoose, por mas que guardo con Date.now, tambien probe con moment, al momento de darme las horas mongoose por la base de datos me aparece con 5 horas de adelanto, como configuro eso de manera sencilla, aun mongoose no ha sacado algun comodin para las diferentes zonas horarias? de haber algun artificio cual seria el mas sencillo y menos propenso a errores al momento de hacer querys o modificaciones..? gracias de antemano

Answer (score 4):

el problema no es Mongoose, tampoco Node.

Como no aportas código de lo que estás haciendo, tampoco aportas un ejemplo claro del comportamiento deseado y del problema que presentas, voy a asumir que te ocurre lo que experimenté hace algún tiempo con Mongoose, Node y MongoDB.

Haciendo estas suposiciones, te comentaré como pude solucionar mi problema.

Al guardar la información de algún documento en MongoDB que contenía un campo llamado `created` el cual era tipo `Date`, en mi controlador de backend hacía por ejemplo lo siguiente:

```
shop.created = Date.now();
```

Como es de esperar me guardaba en MongoDB la fecha de creación del documento `shop`. Siempre que realizo una operación en BD, reviso usando algún DBMS, en este caso usaba la cónsola (shell) de `mongo`. Al revisar la fecha de creación del documento, obtenía lo siguiente:

```
>db.shops.find({ "_id" : ObjectId("5c54994501def83a144c46ef") }, { created: 1 }); // consulta en mongo
>{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c54994501def83a144c46ef"), "created" : ISODate("2018-03-01T19:08:53.555Z") } // respuesta en mongo
```

Allí comencé a ver algo bastante peculiar, ya que al hacer la consulta del campo `created`, noté que me guardaba la fecha con 1 hora menos, es decir, la fecha debía ser: `2018-03-01T20:08:53.555Z`, que era la fecha y hora de mi equipo. Pensaba yo que algo andaba mal, o que algo hacía mal.

Al botar por consola en Node la consulta a la fecha del documento obtenía lo siguiente:

```
const fecha = (req.shop.created).toString();
console.log('Shop created on: ', fecha);
[20:18:59.539] [LOG]    Shop created on:  Thu Mar 01 2018 20:08:53 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00)
```

Entonces, la fecha me la mostraba como yo esperaba, pero agregaba el susodicho `GMT+0100`

Leyendo la [documentación de  MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Date/index.html), entendí que la fecha se almacenaba siempre como `ISO Date`en MongoDB. ¿Pero porqué la almacenaba con 1 hora menos? Empecé a creer que MongoDB convertía la fecha que yo le enviaba desde Node y la almacenaba así. Pero eso no tenía sentido. En ninguna parte de la documentación de MongoDB dice eso. Así que empecé a sospechar de Mongoose. Pero, tampoco tenía sentido. Mongoose es simplemente un ODM. No se mete con fechas y horas y UTC y cosas esotéricas. La respuesta tenía que estar en Node, y más que Node, en JavaScript.

La fecha era correcta, la hora era correcta, pero me agregaba el fulano `GMT+0100`.

Por lo tanto, aunque no estaba muy claro en porqué lo hacía estaba resignado a realizar una serie compleja de operaciones con el string que representaba la fecha. Eso no me convencía. Uno como programador siempre busca optimizar. Y tener que realizar un simple `substring` me parecía un paso innecesario y poco óptimo.

Asi que me puse a investigar un poco. Y encontré lo siguiente. Por eso el comentario del principio.

El método Date.now() de JavaScript devuelve el número de milisegundos transcurridos desde el 01 de Enero de 1970 a las 00:00:00 horas UTC. Lo importante aquí es que la fecha va en UTC. [Javascript Date.now()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date/now).

Misterio resuelto. Resulta que el culpable no era Node, tampoco MongoDB, mucho menos Express o Mongoose. El culpable tampoco es Javascript o V8. El verdadero culpable era yo, que no había entendido realmente el propósito del estándar UTC.

Ahora, volviendo a tu pregunta: *¿Cómo configuro mongoose para que me guarde en zona horaria -5:00?*

La respuesta es: no necesitas configurarlo, solo debes entender el propósito del estándar UTC.

Supongamos que tienes un cliente "A" que se encuentra en zona horaria GMT-05:00 y que realiza una transacción que debe reflejar la fecha y hora en la base de datos. Digamos que es una transacción financiera, un depósito o pago, lo realiza a las 20 horas (hora local). Ahora, tienes otro cliente "B" que está en una zona horaria diferente digamos GMT+01:00, y consulta la transacción realizada por "A" en la base de datos. La diferencia horaria es de 6 horas. La pregunta es, cuando el cliente "B" reciba el resultado de la consulta, ¿Qué fecha y hora recibirá de la base de datos?.

Allí está el asunto. Si cada quien almacena la fecha y hora que se le da la gana, las transacciones de este tipo serían muy difíciles de supervisar o contabilizar. Es por eso que Javascript, al igual que muchos otros lenguajes de programación usan el estándar ISO y convierten la hora local del cliente en hora UTC.

Siempre que la fecha y hora del sistema estén configurados de manera correcta, la fecha devuelta por `Date.now()` será la fecha y hora correspondiente a GMT 00:00:00, más o menos la diferencia horaria local.

Ahora, como no sé exactamente lo que te propones, voy a seguir con el ejemplo anterior de las transacciones financieras.

Si el cliente hace una consulta a la base de datos y pide todas las transacciones realizadas a partir de cierta hora, no debe preocuparse por la diferencia horaria, ya que la BD tiene almacenados los datos en UTC, y el sistema cliente genera fechas en formato UTC, así todo es compatible.

Ejemplo:

1. Cliente "A" realiza un pago el 02-febrero-2019 08:00:00 hora local (GMT -05:00:00). El método `Date.now()` devuelve el siguiente resultado en el equipo cliente: `2019-02-02T13:00:00.000Z` (Esto está en formato UTC = GMT 00:00:00); y lo almacena en BD.
2. Cliente "B" realiza una consulta de los pagos realizados por cliente "A", y digamos que quiere ver los pagos realizados hasta las 12 horas local (GMT +01:00:00) es decir, la hora UTC de la consulta es `11:00:00`. Y la consulta buscará pagos realizados hasta dicha hora.
   Como el pago se efectuó a las `08:00:00 GMT-05:00:00`, se almacenó en base de datos como realizado a las `13:00:00 GMT 00:00:00`. Por lo tanto la consulta no mostrará el pago realizado por el cliente "A" (lo cual es correcto).

Imagina que se hubiera almacenado (a la fuerza) como pago realizado a las 08:00:00 UTC. Es lo que propones en tu pregunta.

También imagina que todos los pagos realizados antes de las 12:00:00 (hora local del cliente "B") están sujetos a un cobro de tarifa baja por pronto pago, y los que se hacen después de las 12:00:00 tienen una tarifa más alta.

Si la fecha del cliente "A" no se almacena en UTC, la aplicación de la tarifa sería injusta a dicho cliente, bien sea a favor o en contra.

Es por eso, que debes respetar y apegarte al estándar. Para algo existe.

Si lo que deseas es no mostrar al cliente la palabra GMT, puedes usar el método `substring` de Javascript y solo muestras la fecha y hora sin el GMT.

Ahora si lo que quieres es mostrar la fecha y hora UTC tal cual se almacena en la BD puedes hacer uso del método `toUTCString()` de Javascript.

Un ejemplo, usando la consola de Node:

```
>let fecha = new Date;
2019-02-02T11:20:46.614Z //esto es UTC, la fecha de mi sistema marca 1 hora más
>fecha.toString(); // usamos el método toString();
>'Sat Feb 02 2019 12:20:46 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00)' // ahora si me muestra la fecha y hora de mi sistema pero agrega el GMT+0100
//supongamos que fecha es lo que recibo de la bd, ¿quiero verlo en UTC?, hago uso de toUTCString()
>fecha.toUTCString();
'Sat, 02 Feb 2019 11:20:46 GMT' // esto es lo que devuelve. Así se almacena en BD
```

En conclusión, no es bueno que cambies el comportamiento del estándar ISO, para algo existe. Al contrario, debes ajustarte al estándar. De esa manera tu código será aceptado universalmente. Es cuestión de entender totalmente de que se trata el estándar y aplicarlo cotidianamente en tu implementación.

Espero que esta aclaración sea una respuesta satisfactoria.

Comment: Magistral explicacion amigo, olvide referenciar con mi codigo pero despues de esa explicacion tan buena ya mi duda quedo resuelta, si me di cuenta que guardaba con horas de mas pero a la hora de traermela a la interface me aparece normalmente con el GMT  y solo tengo que desaparecerlo. te agradezco mucho ya entiendo a cavalidad el estandar. caso cerrado jeje saludos y mil gracias por tu aporte