# Quitar Zona Horaria de una fecha

Tags: primeng

Hola estoy haciendo un formulario en angular 7 y mando la fecha de nacimiento con la zona horaria como quitar la zona horaria de esa fecha obtenida de P-calendar de primeng ya que por lo que el servidor esta en la zona horaria -5 y los clientes en otras zonas  la fecha que se guarda hace la diferencia de horas y necesito que se mantenga como fecha y no como string

Comment: Relacionado: [**¿como configuro mongoose para que me guarde en zona horaria -5:00?**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/234371/como-configuro-mongoose-para-que-me-guarde-en-zona-horaria-500)

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar la libreria de moment.js para quitar la zona horaria.

```
const date = new Date();
const myFormat= 'YYYY-MM-DD';

const myDate = moment(date, 'YYYYMMDDTHHmmss').format(myFormat);
```