# Guardar fecha y hora en mongo db, agrega 5 horas mas a la hora que envio

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Intento registrar una fecha con horas y minutos, pero MongoDB lo almacena sumandole 5 horas mas al número de hora que le envie a guardar.

```javascript
let agenda = {
    perCod: req.body.perCod,
    eveCod: req.body.eveCod,
    imgCod: imgAllCod._id,
    ageHor: req.body.ageHor, // '2021-11-16 08:30:00' Esta es la fecha y horas que envio a MongoDB
    ageTit: req.body.ageTit,
    ageDes: req.body.ageDes,
    ageExp: req.body.ageExp,
    ageAre: req.body.ageAre,
};

console.log(agenda); //
const newAgenda=new Agenda(agenda);
await newAgenda.save();   // se crea un nuevo registro en el documento  
res.json({status: 200 });
```

Pero al guardar la fecha y hora MongoDB lo guarda sumandole 5 horas al número de horas que ingrese:

`ageHor: "2021-11-16T13:30:00.000Z"`

¿Cómo podría hacer para que MongoDB guarde las horas cómo yo se las envío?

Gracias

Comment: Has revisado que timezone estas usando ??

Comment: Esta respuesta contesta tu pregunta? https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/483398/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-manera-correcta-para-guardar-una-fecha-en-milisegundos-en-firestore/483538#483538

Comment: **¿Cómo podría hacer para que MongoDB guarde las horas cómo yo se las envío?** No puedes, a menos que las envíes en zona horaria UTC. Las fechas en MongoDB se almacenan en UTC (antiguo GMT). El valor es calculado en base a la fecha y hora donde se ejecuta el servidor de base de datos. Todo esto tiene una razón que ya he explicado en una respuesta: [¿Cómo configuro Mongoose para que me guarde en zona horaria -5:00?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/234371/como-configuro-mongoose-para-que-me-guarde-en-zona-horaria-500/234726#234726)

Answer (score 2):

No es que la fecha este mal es que se guarda con formato UTC (Tiempo Universal Coordinado), para obtener la fecha que ingresas te puedes usar algo como esto que usara tu `time/zone` local lo puedes comprobar haciendo

```js
const fecha = new Date("2021-11-16T13:30:00.000Z");
console.log(fecha)
```

Puedes imprimir fecha con deferentes formatos y con un time/zone especifico usando librerías como `moment.js`

Si lo que quieres es realmente almacenar la fecha tal cual `2021-11-16T8:30:00.000Z` (no aconsejable) puedes agregar una Z al final de la cadena indicando que la fecha que estas enviado ya se encuentra en en formato UTC, pero esto puede generar problemas a la hora de usar funciones de fecha ya que por defecto se usan como si estuvieran en formato UTC

```js
const fechaUTC = new Date("2021-11-16 08:30:00Z")
console.log('feha real:', fechaUTC) //la fecha real no es la que esperas
console.log('fecha formato UTC: ', fechaUTC.toISOString()) //como se guarda

const fecha = new Date("2021-11-16 08:30:00")
console.log('feha real :', fecha) //fecha real bien
console.log('fecha formato UTC: ', fecha.toISOString()) //como se guarda con formato UTC
```

Por otra parte si no vas realizar tareas especificas con las fechas puedes almacenarlas como string.

puedes ver más información en:

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_formats.asp
https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/save-date-of-birth-of-user-without-timezone/9155/8
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8362952/javascript-output-current-datetime-in-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmsec-format
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35672248/how-to-change-date-timezone-in-mongoose

Comment: Gracias por aclarar!  En realidad se estaba guardando correctamente, el problema era que no lo estaba mostrando de acuerdo a  mi zona horaria