# ¿Como darle zona horaria a una base de datos MongoDB con Mongoose?

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

Estoy teniendo problemas con la zona horaria en mi base de datos ya que esta la default, y quiero establecerle una zona horaria.

Si alguien podría ayudarme se los agradecería

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [como configuro mongoose para que me guarde en zona horaria -5:00?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/234371/como-configuro-mongoose-para-que-me-guarde-en-zona-horaria-500)

Comment: Aquí puedes entender el concepto de zona horaria https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/483398/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-manera-correcta-para-guardar-una-fecha-en-milisegundos-en-firestore/483538#483538

Comment: Perfecto muchas gracias